# Что такое support library v4, v7 их отличия. Что такое sdk, api, build tool, отличия?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-support-library

Столько много чисел в Андроиде, никак не могу разобраться.

- Что такое API, v4,v7,v13,v14 - support.libary их отличия
- Что такое sdk, build-tools, support.design
- Как их различать ?
- И почему Gradle постоянно ругается на эти числа, как понять какие из
  них использовать ??

Comment: День добрый. У нас принято каждый вопрос задавать отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Данные цифры указывают на минимальную поддерживаемую версию, так v4 можно использовать при `minSdkVersion=4`, v7 при `minSdkVersion=7`. Вы не сможете использовать v7 при `minSdkVersion=4`. Для приложения лучше использовать версию ближе к минимальной версии SDK, так как в этом случае используется меньше наследуемого кода. Данные библиотеки необходимы для обратной совместимости кода, написанного для более современных версий Android.
2. `SDK` - Software Development Kit, набор библиотек для разработки. `build-tools` - инструменты сборки приложения. `support.design` - так понимаю вы о `android.support.design`, это библиотека для реализации Material дизайна в приложении.
3. По названиям. Запомнить, понимать суть.
4. Слишком общий вопрос, нужны конкретные примеры ошибок. Скорее всего версии библиотек несовместимы.

Comment: Просто еще какие то из этих чисел должны быть одинаковые в сборке, иначе выдает ошибку ?!. И еще есть **compileSdkVersion**, если мой телефон API 21, а compileSdkVersion 28, то приложение все равно запускается, почему так ?

Comment: Ну если вы добавите в вопрос пример ошибки, думаю я смогу ответить на этот вопрос.

Comment: Да нее, сейчас ошибок нет, я просто хочу разобраться на будущее, просто чтобы настроить проект я постоянно иду на это сайт. Но хочу научиться разбираться в этих числах чтобы вручную настраивать и понимать что я делаю.Как я понимаю чем выше эти числа, тем они лучше ?!